# Make GIFs/Animation of pictures and plots in the same file

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, gif

I am here looking for some advice. I have a data file, basically containing Time, Displacement & Force items I recorded from a mechanical experiment. During the experiment, I recorded a picture of it every 2 seconds.

What I would like to make, is an animation (*.avi, *.gif, ...) of the evolution of the Force vs. Displacement plot and the corresponding pictures above (or below) the plot.

To do so, I first made a script, greatly inspired by another post on the forum, to generate an animation of the plots only. Then another one to open a plot above and a picture below. However, I did not manage to mix these two codes.

Below are the two scripts if needed for more understanding.

**Script 1:** Generation an animated plot

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import pytex as p 
import os

#1- Data reading
for filename in os.listdir("."):
    if (filename[0]=="#"):
        f = open(filename,"r+",encoding="utf8")
        d = f.readlines()
        f.seek(0)
        for i in range(len(d)):
            if i == 21:
                f.write(d[i])
            if i > 23:
                f.write(d[i])
        f.truncate()
        f.close()
        os.rename(filename,filename[1:])

#2- Data for plot
def simData():
    for filename in os.listdir("."):
        data = p.loadDataMatrix(filename)
        tt = data["Time (sec)"]
        x_raw = data["Position (microns)"]
        y_raw = data["Load (N)"]
        x = []
        y = []
        t = 0.
        for i in range(0,len(x_raw),3):
            x = x + [x_raw[i] - x_raw[0]]
            y = y + [y_raw[i]]
            t = tt[i]                
            yield x, y, t

def simPoints(simData):
    xx, yy, t = simData[0], simData[1], simData[2]
    time_text.set_text(time_template%(t))
    line.set_data(xx, yy)
    return line, time_text    

#3- Plotting the figure
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.set_xlim(0, 450)
ax.set_ylim(0, 65)

delay = 1
line, = ax.plot([], [], 'b-', linewidth = 0.6)

time_template = 'Time = %.01f s'
time_text = ax.text(0.05, 0.9, '', transform=ax.transAxes)
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, simPoints, simData, interval=delay, repeat=False, save_count = 50000)

ani.save('animation.mp4', fps=100, dpi=100)
```

**Script 2:** Merging a plot and an image

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as im

fig, (chart, picture) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, figsize=(10,8))

# First, the chart
chart.plot(np.random.random(100))

# Second, an image
image=im.imread("../test_no_8/IMG_004850.tiff")
picture.imshow(image, aspect='auto')
picture.axis('off')


plt.show()
fig.savefig('temp.tiff', dpi=100)
```

Thanks a lot for any help of yours, and please pardon my English if it ever seems unclear.

Comment: You will need to yield the image as well and then update the imshow plot with the image data. `yield x, y, t, img` and `imshow = picture.imshow(image, aspect='auto')´, `imshow.set_data(img)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, it solved my problem.